# Difference between setting array equal to another one, or using three dots

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, spread-syntax

When using hooks in React and using an array as a state, I found that updating only one element of that state array with the setter function did not re-render the component. I was doing this:

```
const [listCollapsed, setListCollapse] = useState(Array(props.list.length).fill(false));

const expandCollapse = (ind) => {
    let newListCollapsed = listCollapsed;
    newListCollapsed[ind] = !listCollapsed[ind];
    setListCollapse(newListCollapsed);

}
```

where expandCollapse was a function called when pressing on a list element. I found that changing the first line of the function to:

```
let newListCollapsed = [...listCollapsed];
```

made it work. I was wondering what the explanation for that was.

Comment: the first way simply renames the variable, while still being the same reference. Second way actually creates a a new copy of the array similar to `newListCollapsed = listCollapsed.slice();` thus creates a new immutable state object

Comment: In the first case, you’re just referencing the original array and mutating it, it’s still the same array so when React does its shallow equality check it assumes nothing has changed. In the second case you’re creating a new array that is a copy of the original. React checks and notices that it’s something different which triggers the rerender.

Comment: Side note: The usual convention is for the `set` function's name to exactly match the state variable's name, so `setListCollapsed` (with the `d`) rather than `setListCollapse`. (Of course, it's just convention, but following convention helps with understanding the code later, collaborating with others, ...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first version broke one of the main React rules by *modifying* state directly (more on that [in this part of the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)). The line

```
let newListCollapsed = listCollapsed;
```

just makes `newListCollapsed` and `listCollapsed` both refer to the same array (the one being used as state), it **doesn't** copy the array. When you do that, you end up with this:

```
state:Ref5461−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                              \      +−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
listCollapsed:Ref5461−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−>|  (array)  | 
                              /      +−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
newListCollapsed:Ref5461−−−−−+       | 0: false  | 
                                     | 1: false  | 
                                     | ...       | 
                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

So

```
setListCollapse(newListCollapsed);
```

doesn't do anything, because that's setting the same array that the state already contains. React doesn't see any change.

But this line:

```
let newListCollapsed = [...listCollapsed];
```

**copies** the array into a new array (using spread notation to spread out its entries into the new array created by the `[]` literal), so you have:

```
state:Ref5461−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                              \      +−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
listCollapsed:Ref5461−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−>|  (array)  | 
                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                                     | 0: false  | 
                                     | 1: false  | 
                                     | ...       | 
                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−+

                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
newListCollapsed:Ref8465−−−−−−−−−−−−>|  (array)  | 
                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                                     | 0: false  | 
                                     | 1: false  | 
                                     | ...       | 
                                     +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

So when you call `setListCollapse(newListCollapsed);`, it's not the same thing, and the change gets made.  That's the correct thing to do.

*(The `Ref####` values in those diagrams are conceptual. They're the object references for the two arrays. An object reference tells the JavaScript engine where the object is in memory. You never see the actual value of an object reference in your code.)*